# TKinter/Python: Error when trying to reuse the output of a function into another function

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to Python and TKinter...

I Try to develop a GUI for interfacing a load cell and a laser distance sensor. Until now, all went fine. However, now I am stuck on the implementation of a new function in my GUI allowing to tare the load cell (zeroing).

My first idea was to change the value of an integer when clicking a "zero force" button and use the value of this integer in a conditional if statement to change the equation that compute the force recorded by the load cell.
The integer is stored in `zero.lc` by the function `zero_lc_state`, the same function also stores the value of the force `force_0` in order to reuse them in the function `mesureY()`.

When runing the code, I get the following error message:

```
runfile('D:/Dropbox/Essai Py/untitled1.py', wdir='D:/Dropbox/Essai Py')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\Dropbox\Essai Py\untitled1.py", line 156, in <module>
    app = App()

  File "D:\Dropbox\Essai Py\untitled1.py", line 67, in __init__
    self.mesureY(self.label_input_Y)

  File "D:\Dropbox\Essai Py\untitled1.py", line 128, in mesureY
    updateY()

  File "D:\Dropbox\Essai Py\untitled1.py", line 121, in updateY
    if self.zero_lc.get() == 1:

AttributeError: 'App' object has no attribute 'zero_lc'
```

I do not understand why the `zero_lc` integer is not recognized. Next I would like to implement the same procedure for distance sensor zeroing.

The others function work properly.

Any advice/help to fix this issue, as well as general comment about my code are very welcome!
All the best,
Romain

here is the full code:

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.font as TkFont
import time
import numpy
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from Phidget22.Phidget import *
from Phidget22.Devices.VoltageRatioInput import *
from Phidget22.Devices.CurrentInput import *
import time

class App():
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() 
        ### Init Load cell
        self.lc = VoltageRatioInput()
        self.lc.setDeviceSerialNumber(559546)
        self.lc.setChannel(1)
        self.lc.openWaitForAttachment(5000)

        ### Init laser sensor
        self.laser = CurrentInput()
        self.laser.setDeviceSerialNumber(559546)
        self.laser.setChannel(0)
        self.laser.openWaitForAttachment(5000)
        self.laser.setPowerSupply(PowerSupply.POWER_SUPPLY_24V)
 
        # Create a container
        self.root = tkinter.Tk()
        self.root.geometry("1900x850")
        self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.callback)
        self.titleFont = TkFont.Font(root=self.root, family='Verdana', size=25, weight='bold')

        ## Create frames
        self.graph_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.root,highlightbackground="black",highlightthickness=1)
        self.entry_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.root,highlightbackground="black",highlightthickness=1)

        ## Create entries and buttons
        self.entry_X = tkinter.Entry(self.entry_frame)
        self.entry_Y = tkinter.Entry(self.entry_frame)
        self.button_measure = tkinter.Button(self.entry_frame,text="Measure", command=self.increment)
        self.button_zero_lc = tkinter.Button(self.entry_frame,text="Zero Force", command=self.zero_lc_state)

        ## Create labels entries
        self.label_input_X = tkinter.Label(self.entry_frame, text="1", anchor='c', background ="gray", borderwidth=10, relief='sunken', foreground="yellow", font=self.titleFont, width=8)
        self.label_input_Y = tkinter.Label(self.entry_frame, text="1", anchor='c', background ="gray", borderwidth=10, relief='sunken', foreground="yellow", font=self.titleFont, width=8)
        
        self.mesureX(self.label_input_X)
        self.mesureY(self.label_input_Y)

        ## Row and columns configuration
        # main frame
        tkinter.Grid.rowconfigure(self.root, 0, weight=1)
        tkinter.Grid.columnconfigure(self.root, 0, weight=1)
        tkinter.Grid.columnconfigure(self.root, 1, weight=1)

        # graph frame
        tkinter.Grid.rowconfigure(self.graph_frame, 0, weight=1)
        tkinter.Grid.columnconfigure(self.graph_frame, 0, weight=1)
        
        # entry frame
        tkinter.Grid.rowconfigure(self.entry_frame, 0, weight=1)
        tkinter.Grid.rowconfigure(self.entry_frame, 1, weight=1)
        tkinter.Grid.rowconfigure(self.entry_frame, 2, weight=1)
        tkinter.Grid.columnconfigure(self.entry_frame, 0, weight=1)
        tkinter.Grid.columnconfigure(self.entry_frame, 1, weight=1)

        ## Griding 
        self.graph_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.entry_frame.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky="esw")
                 
        self.label_input_X.grid(column=0, row=3, sticky="esw", pady=10)
        self.label_input_Y.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky="esw", pady=10)
 
        self.button_zero_lc.grid(column=1, row=4, columnspan= 2, sticky="nsew", pady=10)
        self.button_measure.grid(column=0, row=5, columnspan= 3, sticky="nsew", pady=10)
  
        ## X and Y arrays
        self.point_X = []
        self.point_Y = []
        
        ### zero lc state init
        self.zero_lc = tkinter.IntVar()
        
        ## Create Plot region
        fig = Figure()
        self.ax = fig.add_subplot(111, xlabel="Displacement", ylabel="Force")
        self.plot, = self.ax.plot(self.point_X, self.point_Y, 'bo')
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,master=self.graph_frame)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nsew")


    def zero_lc_state(self):
            self.zero_lc.set(1)
            self.force_0 = -21641*self.lc.getVoltageRatio() - 0.4899
            return self.zero_lc
            return self.force_0
    
    def mesureY(self,labely):
        def updateY():
            self.analog_valueY  = self.lc.getVoltageRatio() 
            #self.force = -21641*self.analog_valueY - 0.4899
            if self.zero_lc.get() == 1:
                self.force = (-21641*self.analog_valueY  - 0.4899 )- self.force_0
            else: 
                self.force = -21641*self.analog_valueY - 0.4899
            
            self.label_input_Y.config(text= str(round(self.force, 3)) + " N")
            self.label_input_Y.after(10,updateY)
        updateY()
        
    def mesureX(self,labelx):
        def updateX():
            self.analog_valueX  = self.laser.getCurrent() 
            self.distance = ((self.analog_valueX *1000-4)/16)*200
            self.label_input_X.config(text= str(round(self.distance, 3)) + " mm")
            self.label_input_X.after(10,updateX)
        updateX()
        
    
     
    def increment(self):
        new_X = ((self.laser.getCurrent() *1000-4)/16)*200
        new_Y = float(-21739*self.lc.getVoltageRatio()- 0.5188)
        self.point_X.append(new_X)
        self.point_Y.append(new_Y)
        self.plot.set_data(self.point_X,self.point_Y)
        self.ax.set_xlim(min(self.point_X)*0.9, max(self.point_X)*1.1)
        self.ax.set_ylim(min(self.point_Y)*0.9, max(self.point_Y)*1.1)
        self.canvas.draw() 

    def callback(self):
        self.lc.close()
        self.laser.close()
        self.root.destroy()

    
app = App()
app.root.mainloop()
```

Comment: could be caused by the wrapper: try this: `def updateY(self)` so that the self argument gets passed to the other function

Comment: Thank you Matiiss, but unfortunately it did not solve the problem ...

Comment: In `App.__init__()`, you are calling `updateY()` (which accesses `zero_lc`) about 35 lines before you actually initialize `zero_lc`.  Moving the initialization up towards the top of the method would likely fix the problem.

Comment: @Matiiss No did you read the code? `updateY()`

Comment: @jasonharper, thank you very much it solves the issue ! I put the zero lc init just after the creation of the container. However I do not really understand why it does  the job ... Is it because putting the init at the begining of the method let much more time to zero_lc to be actually stored?

Comment: `__init__` is function as any other function and code is executed line by line - so order of lines is imported. `__init__` uses `mesureY()` (which need `self.zero_lc`) before line `self.zero_lc = ...` - so `self.zero_lc` doesn't exists yet when it executes `mesureY()`. It has nothing to do if you put `__init__` before other methods , and it  doesn't have more time to run. If you try to do `print(x)` before `x = 1` then you get the same problem.